# Error when getting File from storage

Tags: android, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I am following a tutorial [here](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/saving-loading-bitmaps-to-the-android-device-storage-internal-external/).

When I go to get a bitmap from internal storage after storing the bitmap like this:

```
    public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap default_b) {

    try {
    // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
    // the OutputStream
    FileOutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
    default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();

    return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    return false;
    }
    }
```

in one class and try to get it like this:

```
   public boolean isSdReadable() {

    boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    Log.i("isSdReadable", "External storage card is readable.");
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // We can only read the media
    Log.i("isSdReadable", "External storage card is readable.");
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    } else {
    // Something else is wrong. It may be one of many other
    // states, but all we need to know is we can neither read nor write
    mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
    }

    return mExternalStorageAvailable;
    }

public Bitmap getThumbnail(String filename) {

    final String APP_PATH_SD_CARD = "/DesiredSubfolderName/";
    final String APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD = "thumbnails";

    String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + APP_PATH_SD_CARD + APP_THUMBNAIL_PATH_SD_CARD;
    Bitmap thumbnail = null;

    // Look for the file on the external storage
    try {
    if (isSdReadable() == true) {
    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullPath + "/" + filename);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("getThumbnail() on external storage", e.getMessage());
    }

    // If no file on external storage, look in internal storage
    if (thumbnail == null) {
    try {
    File filePath = Context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
    return thumbnail;
    }



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Try to reuse the views
    ImageView view = (ImageView) convertView;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    boolean checked = (mCheckBox==null)?false:(((CheckBox)  mCheckBox).isChecked());
    // if convert view is null then create a new instance else reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new ImageView(Context);
        Log.d("GridViewAdapter", "new imageView added");
    }
    if(checked = true){
        isSdReadable();
        getThumbnail(toString());
    }
    view.setImageResource(drawables.get(position));
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    view.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    view.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
    return view;
}
```

I get this error in my Logcat (please note that this is all it shows):

```
12-07 17:00:21.802: I/isSdReadable(30831): External storage card is readable.
12-07 17:00:21.802: I/isSdReadable(30831): External storage card is readable.
12-07 17:00:21.802: E/getThumbnail() on internal storage(30831): /data/data/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget/files/com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.GridViewAdapter@4052f1c8 (No such file or directory)
```

So I know the error is in this section of coding:

```
// If no file on external storage, look in internal storage
    if (thumbnail == null) {
    try {
    File filePath = Context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("getThumbnail() on internal storage", ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
    return thumbnail;
    }
```

But I can't figure out why I am getting that error.

Why is that?

Comment: Well, it's telling you the directory doesn't exist.  Does it?  Furthermore, what is the observed failure?

Comment: Have you checked if file is written correctly without errors, it looks like the file isn't there.

Comment: @svenoaks How can I check to see if the file is there or not? (besides it giving me an error of course)

Comment: You can try File.list().  Try it at different points in the path till you find the place where something doesn't exist.